# JSONPath filter top level key with certain value

Tags: json, jsonpath

Consider the following JSON:

```json
{
    "expensive": 10,
    "abc":10
}
```

I would like to write a filter that returns true if the key `abc` equals `10`, i.e. on the example above the answer is `true`, while on the following example it is `false`:

```json
{
    "expensive": 10
}
```

because there is no such key `abc`.

I have tried these filters:

1. `$[?(@ == 10)]` returns `[10,10]` on the first json and `[10]` on the second, but I want to enforce the check on the `abc` field, i.e. the second should return nothing. how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have an array of input objects and want to filter them.

```json
[{
    "expensive": 10,
    "abc":10
}, {
    "expensive": 10
}]
```

Here `$[?(@.abc == 10)]` returns

```json
[
  {
    "expensive": 10,
    "abc": 10
  }
]
```

and `$[?(@.abc == 10)].expensive` returns

```json
[
  10
]
```